# How to implement this property file?

Tags: java, parsing, properties

I have this piece of data (this is just one part of one line of the whole file):

```
000000055555444444******4444      YY
```

I implemented this CSV config file to be able to read each part of the data and parse it:

```
128-12,140-22,YY
```

The first pair (128-12) represent at what position in the line to start reading and then the amount of characters to read, that first pair is for the account number.

The second pair if for the card number.

And the thir parameter is for the registry name.

Anyways, what I do is String.split(","), and then assign the array[0] as the account number and so on.

But I want to change that CSV config file to a Property file, but I'm not sure of how to implement that solution, if I use a Properties file I'd have to add a bunch of if/then in order to properly map my values, here's what I'm thinking of doing:

```
Property cfg = new Property();
cfg.put("fieldName", "accountNumber");
cfg.put("startPosition", "128");
cfg.put("length", "12");
```

But I'd have to say if("fieldName".equals("accountNumber")) then assign accountNumber; is there a way to implement this in such a way that I could avoid implementing all this decisions? right now with my solution I don't have to use ifs, I only say accountNumber = array[0]; and that's it, but I don't think that's a good solution and I think that using Property would be more elegant or efficient

EDIT:

This probably needs some more clarification, this data I'm showing is part of a parsing program that I'm currently doing for a client; the data holds information for many many of their customers and I have to parse a huge mess of data that I receive from them, into something more readable in order to convert it to a PDF file, so far the program is under production but I'm trying to refactor it a little bit. All the customer's information is saved into different Registry classes, each class having it's own set of fields with unique information, lets say that this is what RegistryYY would look like:

```
class RegistryYY extends Registry{
  String name;
  String lastName;
  PhysicalAddress address;

  public RegistryYY(String dataFromFile) {
  }
}
```

I want to implement the Property solution, because in that way, I could make the Property for parsing the file, or interpreting the data correctly to be owned by each Registry class, I mean, a Registry should know what data it needs from the data received from the file right?, I think that if I do it that way, I could make each Registry an Observer and they would decide if the current line read from the file belongs to them by checking the registry name stored in the current line and then they'd return an initialized Registry to the calling object which only cares about receiving and storing a Registry class.

EDIT 2:

I created this function to return the value stored in each line's position:

```
public static String getField(String fieldParams, String rawData){
        // splits the field
        String[] fields = fieldParams.split("-");

        int fieldStart = Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);   // get initial position of the field
        int fieldLen = Integer.parseInt(fields[1]); // get length of field

        // gets field value
        String fieldValue = FieldParser.getStringValue(rawData, fieldStart, fieldLen);

        return fieldValue;      
    }
```

Which works with the CSV file, I'd like to change the implementation to work with the Property file instead.

Comment: @VinceEmigh because the OP has probably many "fieldName". I don't think properties is the good storage for that. Maybe YAML : http://yamlbeans.sourceforge.net/ (see the phone numbers example)

Comment: From what I understand, the OP has some kind of fixed length data (startPosition = 128, length = 12 and startPosition = 140, length = 22)

Comment: @VinceEmigh as RC said, I have many, many fields, I stated at the start of my question that what I was showing was only a part of a line of data, the file can have up to 800K+ lines of data, and so far the largest file had information for 20k different clients.

Comment: @RC. yeah...Althought the data is messy, it has a fixed length for each field, even if they're a million lines, position 128 would always be the initial position for the account number, which would always be 12 characters long.

Comment: @VinceEmigh there are many more attributes, I only listed the ones for the Registry name, account numbers and cardnumber, but depending on the type of Registry, there could be up to 40 more attributes, that's why I edited the question above.

Comment: @VinceEmigh your YAML suggestion seems like what I was looking for, how can I mark your reply as an answer?

Comment: @AnubisLockward It was my suggestion. Feel free to transform it into some "self answer" if you want, you could probably get some rep. from that ;)

Comment: @RC. ups..my bad, thanks anyways for the suggestion, I'll experiment a bit with it thought but it looks like what I wanted to implement. Thanks a lot...

Comment: NO problem. NB: the link to the YAML lib is the first I found with google, so there might be some better one out there.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you need to have the record layout exposed to the outside world ? does it need to be configurable ?

I think your proposed approached of using the Property file is better than your current approach of using the CSV file since it is more descriptive and meaningful. I would just add a "type" attribute to your Property definition as well to enforce your conversion i.e. for Numeric/String/Date/Boolean.

I wouldnt use an "if" statement to process your property file. You can load all the properties into an Array at the beginning and then iterate around the array for each line of your data file and process that section accordingly something like pseudo code below,

```
for each loop of data-file{
    SomeClass myClass = myClassBuilder(data-file-line)
}

myClassBuilder SomeClass (String data-file-line){
     Map<column, value> result = new HashMap<>
     for each attribute of property-file-list{
         switch attribute_type {
               Integer:
                  result.put(fieldname, makeInteger(data-file-line, property_attribute)
               Date:
                  result.put(fieldname, makeDate(data-file-line, property_attribute)
               Boolean : 
                  result.put(fieldname, makeBoolean(data-file-line, property_attribute)
               String  :
                  result.put(fieldname, makeBoolean(data-file-line, property_attribute)
               ------- etc
          }
     }
     return new SomeClass(result)
}
```

}

If your record layout doesnt need to be configurable then you could do all the conversion inside your Java application only and not even use a Property file.

If you could get your data in XML format then you could use the JAXB framework and simply have your data definition in an XML file.

Comment: for reference, here's an old question I asked about the project I'm working in, I'm posting only the RegistroCL class, I want to make each Registry own the Properties for it's own creation so that I only have to worry about reading lines and notifying listeners and the'll decide if the line belongs to them and create an instance of the Registry or not: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142514/system-to-process-data-from-a-specific-client

Comment: By the way, so far even thought the project is in production, the client is always making a lot of changes to the layout of the data, that's why for now, I need it to be configurable. @robbie70

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to the guys who helped me, @robbie70, @RC. and @VinceEmigh.

I used YAML to parse a file called "test.yml" with the following information in it:

```
statement:
  - fieldName: accountNumber
    startPosition: 128
    length: 12
  - fieldName: cardNumber
    startPosition: 140
    length: 22
  - fieldName: registryName
    startPosition: 162
    length: 2
```

This is what I made:

```
// Start of main

String fileValue = "0222000000002222F                                                                                           00000000000111110001000000099999444444******4444      YY";
        YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(new FileReader("test.yml"));
        Object object = reader.read();      
        System.out.println(object);

        Map map = (Map) object;

        List list = (List) map.get("statement");

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Map map2 = (Map) list.get(i);

            System.out.println("Value: " + foo(map2, fileValue));
        }       
    }

// End of main

    public static String foo(Map map, String source) {
        int startPos = Integer.parseInt((String) map.get("startPosition"));
        int length = Integer.parseInt((String) map.get("length"));

        return getField(startPos, length, source);
    }

    public static String getField(int start, int length, String source) {
        return source.substring(start, start+length);
    }
```

It correctly displays the output:

```
Value: 000000099999
Value: 444444******4444      
Value: YY
```

I know that maybe the config file has some lists and other unnecessary values and what nots, and that maybe the program needs a little improvement, but I think that I can take it from here and implement what I had in mind.

EDIT:

I made this other one, using Apache Commons, this is what I have in the configuration property file:

```
#properties defining the statement file

#properties for account number
statement.accountNumber.startPosition = 128
statement.accountNumber.length = 12
statement.account.rules = ${statement.accountNumber.startPosition} ${statement.accountNumber.length}

#properties for card number
statement.cardNumber.startPosition = 140
statement.cardNumber.length = 22
statement.card.rules = ${statement.cardNumber.startPosition} ${statement.cardNumber.length}

#properties for registry name
statement.registryName.startPosition = 162
statement.registryName.length = 2
statement.registry.rules = ${statement.registryName.startPosition} ${statement.registryName.length}
```

And this is how I read it:

```
// Inside Main


String valorLeido = "0713000000007451D                                                                                           00000000000111110001000000099999444444******4444      YY";     

    Parameters params = new Parameters();
    FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> builder =
        new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
        .configure(params.properties()
                .setFileName("config.properties"));

    try {
        Configuration config = builder.getConfiguration();          

        Iterator<String> keys = config.getKeys();

        String account = getValue(getRules(config, "statement.account.rules"), valorLeido);
        String cardNumber = getValue(getRules(config, "statement.card.rules"), valorLeido);
        String registryName = getValue(getRules(config, "statement.registry.rules"), valorLeido);
    } catch (org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
// End of Main    

public static String getRules(Configuration config, String rules) {
    return config.getString(rules);
}

public static String getValue(String rules, String source) {
    String[] tokens = rules.split(" ");

    int startPos = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    int length = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);

    return getField(startPos, length, source);
}
```

I'm not entirely sure, I think that with the YAML file it looks simpler, but I really like the control I get with the Apache Commons Config, since I can pass around the Configuration object to each registry, and the registry knows what "rules" it wants to get, let's say that the Registry class only cares about "statement.registry.rules" and that's it, with the YAML option I'm not entirely sure of how to do that yet, maybe I'll need to experiment with both options a little bit more, but I like where this is going.

PS:

That weird value I used in fileValue is what I'm dealing with, now add nearly 1,000 characters to the length of the line and you'll understand why I want to have a config file for parsing it (don't ask why....clients be crazy)